# This is Banach space?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let me denote by $C_{0}(\mathbb{R})$  the set of continuous functions which tend to zero at + and - $\infty$. I am wondering if it is true that  $(C_{0}(\mathbb{R}), \Vert . \Vert_{\infty})$ is a Banach space and why ? Thanks.

Comment: Clearly this is a normed linear space. All you need to do is show that it is complete (or not). If you wanted to show it is a Banach space, you need to show that if you have a Cauchy sequence of functions in $C_0$ that: 1) the limit (function) exists, 2) this function is continuous, and 3) it decays at $\pm\infty$.

Comment: Yes, thanks Cameron.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\{u_n\}_{n\in\mathbb N}\subset C_0(\mathbb R)$ be a Cauchy sequence, i.e., for every $\varepsilon>0$, there exists an $N=N(\varepsilon)>0$, such that
$$
m,n\ge N\quad\Longrightarrow\quad \|u_m-u_n\|_\infty=\sup_{x\in\mathbb R}\lvert u_m(x)-u_n(x)\rvert<\varepsilon.
$$
We shall show that there exists a $u\in C_0(\mathbb R)$, such that $\|u_n-u\|_\infty\to 0$.

Fix now an interval $[-M,M]$. Then $\big\{u_n\mid_{[-M,M]}\big\}$ is also a $\|\cdot\|_\infty$-Cauchy sequence and as $C[-M,M]$ is complete, then 
$u_n\mid_{\,[-M,M]}\to v^M\in C[-M,M]$.

This is true for every $M>0$. In particular, if $M'>M$, then $v^{M'}|_{\,[-M,M]}=v^M$.

In this way we can define a $v :\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$, such that $v|_{\,[-M,M]}=v^M$, 
and clearly $v$ is continuous (a locally uniformly limit of continuous functions) and $u_n\to v$ uniformly in every closed interval. It remains to show that 
$\|u_n-v\|_{\infty}\to 0$ and
$v\in C_0(\mathbb R)$.

1. $\|u_n-v\|_{\infty}\to 0$. 
   Let $\varepsilon>0$. If $n\ge N(\varepsilon/2)$, then for all $x\in\mathbb R$
   $$\|u_m(x)-u_n(x)\|_\infty<\varepsilon/2,$$
   for $m,n\ge N(\varepsilon/3)$. 
   Letting $m\to\infty$ we get that $u_m(x)\to v(x)$, pointwise, and thus $$\|v(x)-u_n(x)\|_\infty\le\varepsilon/2<\varepsilon,$$ for all $x\in\mathbb R$ and $n\ge N(\varepsilon/2)$. Therefore, $\|u_n-v\|_{\infty}\to 0$.
2. $v\in C_0(\mathbb R)$. We need to show that for every $\varepsilon>0$, there exists an $M>0$, such that $|x|>M$ implies that $\lvert v(x)\rvert<\varepsilon$. 
   Let $n=N(\varepsilon/2)$. Then for all $x\in\mathbb R$:
   $$
   \lvert u_n(x)-v(x)\rvert <\varepsilon/2.\tag{1}
   $$
   But $\lim_{|x|\to\infty}u_n(x)=0$, and hence there exists an $M>0$, such that $|x|>M$ implies that $$\lvert u_n(x)\rvert<\varepsilon/2.\tag{2}$$ Adding $(1)$ and $(2)$ we obtain that
   $|x|>M$ implies that $\lvert v(x)\rvert<\varepsilon$, and hence $v\in C_0(\mathbb R)$.

Comment: Many thanks Yiorgos for this nice proof.